# resampling trade data into olhc format

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have a lot of raw trade data that i want mess around with, so im wanting to change it into olhc format to make analyzing it easier.  So, in quickly researching this i came upon pandas in python, and more specifically this command

```
df.resample('60s', how={'price': 'ohlc'})
```

So, i have all my data in csv files, so what im running is

```
df=pd.read_csv("xao.csv")
df.resample('60s', how={'price': 'ohlc'})
```

and if im correct this is the correct format and commands, my issue is the time format i believe, and im not sure how to go about changing the format  of the time in the csv.

My csv is in the following format

unixtimecode,price,volume

so a sample line is

```
1419031147  453.3   0.050
```

so what is an easy way to go about converting the time from a unix timestamp to a useable time format for the resample code?

So, thanks to nitin i now have my time in what i believe to be the correct format, running `print df.tail()` yields

```
                       Date    price  volume
824184  2014-12-19 23:19:07  434.9     0.050
824185  2014-12-19 23:19:48  434.7     0.011
824186  2014-12-19 23:19:48  434.9     0.039
824187  2014-12-19 23:20:29  434.9     0.050
824188  2014-12-19 23:21:09  434.9     0.050
```

which i believe is correct, but running `df.resample('60s', how={'price': 'ohlc'})`still doesnt work, it gives the error `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex`, why is this?

edit2, managed to get it working.

For anyone who finds this via google/future me heres the code i used

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv("xao.csv")
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']*int(1e9))
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date, unit = 's')
df = df.set_index('Date').astype('float64')
df['price'].resample('60s',how='ohlc')
```

Comment: So this question isn't about resampling, but rather about properly parsing data files. You should probably edit the title and question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yon convert a unixtimestamp by using pandas to_datetime. You can read in the timecode from the csv as an integer and then apply pd.to_datetime

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'timecode' : [1419031147], 'price' : [453.3], 'volume' : [0.050]})
pd.to_datetime(df.timecode, unit = 's')
```

This will yield,

```
0   2014-12-19 23:19:07
Name: timecode, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: so, thanks for this.  I got the time converted into this format   2014-12-19 23:19:07  453.3   0.050 but i cant seem to get the resample code to work.  It still errors with "TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex", any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You should make date column as index for resample to work.